# Assign a parameter value to many struct members in a contructor similar function Rust

Tags: generics, rust

I have an issue with a simple struct creation with generic type, as follows:

```rust
struct Point3<T> {
    pub x: T,
    pub y: T,
    pub z: T,
}

impl<T> Point3<T>
{
    fn create3(vx: T, vy: T, vz: T) -> Point3<T> {
        Point3::<T> {
            x: vx,
            y: vy,
            z: vz,
        }
    }

    fn create1(v: T) -> Point3<T> {
        Point3::<T> {
            x: v,
            y: v,
            z: v,
        }
    }
}
```

but when I tried to compile it, I got an error :

```rust
fn create1(v: T) -> Point3<T> {
   |                - move occurs because `v` has type `T`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
34 |         Point3::<T> {
35 |             x: v,
   |                - value moved here
36 |             y: v,
   |                ^ value used here after move
```

I understand than `v` is moved in `x` and so not available for `y` or `z`.
so it seems I need to copy it, but I don't know how to do that, nor implement the `Copy` trait for `T` since its a generic type

If I pass `v` by ref I have another error

I'm sure it's pretty simple, but as a c/c++ dev rust is complex to me for the moment :)

Comment: When you implement the struct, specify: `impl<T: Copy> Point3<T> { ... }`

Comment: wow, it was so simple finally. dont know this way to specify the trait of a type; thanks @AlexeyLarionov

Comment: Note though that by default only few types implement `Copy` (e.g. numeric types), you may consider using `Clone` trait, and thus use `v.clone()` everywhere you want to copy the value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When working with type parameters, the only thing that Rust assumes about the type is that it is `Sized`. Any other constraints on the type parameter must be explicitly written out.

Also, Rust's default move semantics mean that a value can have only a single owner, and that once a value is "moved out of" a place, it is no longer valid there. You can opt out of this behaviour by implementing `Copy`, though this is only valid for types that can be meaningfully `memcpy`-ed, so many things can't use this (anything with a `Drop` impl, `&mut T`, and more). TLDR, it's a fairly restrictive bound to put on an API.

The much more general case is `Clone`, which is a supertrait of `Copy` (which means: any `T` that implements `Copy`, also implements `Clone`). The difference is that `Clone` is potentially an expensive operation, potentially requiring heap allocations, and must be explicitly called via `Clone::clone`, but the tradeoff is that it is far more widely applicable.

So I'd suggest rewriting your code as follows:

```rust
// this function doesn't need to impose any special bounds on T,
// since it never needs to be cloned
impl<T> Point3<T> {
  fn create3(x: T, y: T, z: T) -> Self {
    Self { x, y, z }
  }
}

// this function does require clone, so we have to add the bound
impl<T: Clone> Point3<T> {
  fn create1(v: T) -> Self {
    Self {
      x: v.clone(),
      y: v.clone(),
      z: v,
    }
  }
}
```

This allows your API to be used by significantly more types, but also doesn't add any performance overhead for `Copy` types, since the `Clone` implementation for a type that is also `Copy` is basically a standard `memcpy`.

Admittedly, with a struct called `Point3`, it's probably only going to be used for numbers, so the `Copy` vs `Clone` distinction isn't very relevant, but in the general case, a `Clone` bound is more widely usable.